# A module cannot have multiple default exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I have only one `export default` line in my code. However, in WebStorm with Typescript, I get this TS Error:

> Ts2528: a module cannot have multiple default exports

Here is the code:

```js
ts import { ModelCreator } from 'entities/model-creator' export default ModelCreator()
```

Answer (score 139):

**The Quick Way**

As sometimes you can just reopen a file as stated in other answers, it doesn't always help, however.

When you see lags like this one (and other weirdness from TS service), you can restart the TypeScript service using the following way:

[image: New option]

See more details on [TypeScript tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/typescript-compiler-tool-window.html) help center page.

---

**Previous functionality (prior versions)**

Restart TypeScript service by opening a TypeScript tool window and clicking on the "Restart" button (3rd button on the right side of the panel):

[image]

Comment: This solved my Intellij *"A module cannot have multiple default exports"* error as well

Comment: Definitely better than restarting IDE. However still reproducible on PhpStorm 2020.2.3

Comment: Pity they merged TypeScript into the Problems pane in 2020.3, I can't see how to restart TypeScript now.

Comment: Thank you! This tip still paying dividends in 2021 with a react component issue I had with a default export

Comment: Upd: Seems like this update resolved the issue finally https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-47248

Comment: @SerhiiMatrunchyk Just encountered it today, on IntelliJ 2022.1.3 so I don't think it's fully fixed yet.

Comment: @seveneights yeah, I also encounter this from time to time, seems like it's still there..

Answer (score 67):

I had the same error. After restarting WebStorm it worked again.

Comment: Same issue in PyCharm

Comment: Same issue in IntelliJ Idea

Comment: for me, it worked just after reopening the file. so for ex: close the file which shows this error and reopen it. so, in this case, u can save the time of restarting a webstorm.. I hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 24):

Quickest way: Close and reopen the file!

Comment: work in phpstorm  xD

Answer (score 0):

You Close File and Reopen file

After error Fix

Answer (score -1):

Look for typing error between "export defulat navbaar" with "const navbar function()"